# Python: Extracting a Dictionary from a List, and copy it to another Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

i have a list that contains a few dictionaries. I want to extract the dictionaries from this list and add them to a new dictionary.

```
testList = [{"Name":"Jim"},{"Age":"25"},{"Location":"UK"}]
```

however, i can't quite get it to work. so far, I've tried a simple for loop to sift through the list and update it to a new target accordingly, if the entries found in it happen to be a dictionary:

```
for dictionary in testList:
  if dictionary is dict:
    for k, v in dictionary.items(): 
        newDict = {}
        newDict.update(k,v)
```

i managed to get it working, but it seemingly only updated the last dictionary entry in the list and not just add them all to it when i was experimenting with earlier code. I also tried to take a copy of it calling the '.copy()' method but that had no luck either. Now the newDict, when i print it, is empty still! anyone know what i'm doing wrong? i'd appreciate any help here because i have a feeling i'm not too far off! i can print the length of the list and see it has 3 items, which is expected. So i'm not sure why when i had it partially working before that it only lifted the last dictionary only.

Comment: `newDict = {}` is executed everytime and it re-initialises to empty dictionary. So what you have in the end is what you updated at the last.

Comment: Do you expect that `testList` contains anything else than dictionaries? If not, you do not need to test if each item is a dictionary, just assume it is.

Comment: You forgot to show us the desired result.

Comment: You also mean `isinstance(dictionary, dict)`, not `dictionary is dict` (if it is necessary to test this at all).

Comment: And you are also using `update` wrongly. You would just give it a dictionary as argument - no need to loop over the items.

Comment: testList might contain something else down the line for what i'm testing in the future. So i thought it might make sense to test if the entries in it are dictionaries. Sorry by the way guys i'm kinda new to this, lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected version of your code:

```
testList = [{"Name":"Jim"},{"Age":"25"},{"Location":"UK"}]

newDict = {}
for dictionary in testList:
  if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
    newDict.update(dictionary)

print(newDict)
```

Points to note:

- initialise `newDict` *outside* the loop
- `isinstance` to test if `dictionary` is a `dict`; `dictionary is dict` would test if it is the same object as the type `dict` - this will almost certainly evaluate `False`. (And you only need to do the test if there is some possibility that it might not be a dictionary.)
- the argument to `update` is a dictionary. It will copy all the items across, and there is no need to loop over the items explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to programming and Python but here's my idea.

```
testList = [{"Name":"Jim"},{"Age":"25"},{"Location":"UK"}]

newDict = {}
for dictionary in testList:
    newDict.update(dictionary)

print(newDict)
```

What I think caused the problem was that you put the dictionary inside the for loop and it should be outside. I hope it helped and feel free to correct my solution.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't check in this manner: `dictionary is dict`. Instead of it you check if the type is `dict` or not like `type(dictionary) is dict`
2. you are creating new dictionary for every element in the list and this is replacing the old values.
3. The syntax of update is `newDict.update({k:v})` or you can simply write like this `newDict[k] = v`.

You can modify your code like this.

```
testList = [{"Name":"Jim"},{"Age":"25"},{"Location":"UK"}]

newDict = {}

for dictionary in testList:
  if type(dictionary) is dict:
    for k, v in dictionary.items(): 
        newDict.update({k: v})

print(newDict)
```